# iOS 11 browsers image bug

Tags: ios, css, image, reactjs

I'm getting the following error in iOS 11 when scrolling through the page.
(In Firefox, Safari and Chrome). In Android devices the error is not happening.

These are background images, I don't know if that could be the reason that's causing the error.

[image]

[image: Intended image]

Image 2 shows how the image is intended and shown in Android.

```
<div
  className="shelf-page-lists-icons-background"
  style={containerImage}
/>
<div
  style={styles.container}
>
  <p style={styles.listsTitle}>{list.title}</p>
</div>


  CSS 

  containerImage = {
    backgroundImage: url(${list.image}),
    backgroundSize: 'cover',
    height: 150,
    borderRadius: 4,
    position: 'absolute',
    width: imageWidth,
    overflow: 'hidden',
  }

  container: {
    height: 150,
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    marginBottom: 10,
    padding: '0px 40px 13px 16px',
  },


  .shelf-page-lists-icons-background {
    opacity: 0.84;
    filter: brightness(0.4)
  }
```

Comment: You'll probably need to post some code before you get a decent response. Absolute positioning on your images could be the problem as you say but without code it's just guesswork.

Comment: I can confirm this issue and it seems it appear on the actual iphone device but NOT in the simulator - very strange

Answer (score 8):

The problem seems to be related to the filters: [Slow CSS Filters on iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21363230/slow-css-filters-on-iphone)

I added these properties as metioned above and it seems to work:

```
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
-webkit-perspective: 1000;
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
```

Comment: I don’t understand why this works, but it does! Thanks. In my case, the bug was even affecting non-filtered images further down the page.

Comment: I wasn't able to make this solution work for me. Instead, I do not apply the filter on iOS devices.

Comment: I have no idea why, but these settings fixed the problem I am having with using `filter: grayscale(x)` on mobile safari.